# How do I circulate an image in Swift using/without using UIBezierPath?

Tags: ios, swift, uibezierpath

I am trying to make an image circulating using `UIBezierPath`. Here is the code I am using to determine the image's `x` and `y` coordinates, its width and its height.

```
var frm : CGRect = self.image.frame
    let originX = frm.origin.x
    let originY = frm.origin.y
    let originWidth = frm.size.width
    let originHeight = frm.size.height
    self.image.frame = frm
```

However, if I put `originX` and `originY` in this code:

```
let path = UIBezierPath()
    path.moveToPoint(CGPoint(x: originX+50, y: originY))
    path.addCurveToPoint(CGPoint(x: originX-20, y: originY),
    controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: originX+20, y: originY),
    controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: originX-10, y: originY))

    let anim = CAKeyframeAnimation(keyPath: "position")

    // set the animations path to our bezier curve
    anim.path = path.CGPath

    anim.repeatCount = Float.infinity
    anim.duration = 5.0

    image.layer.addAnimation(anim, forKey: "animate position along path")
```

The image just stays at the top left of the screen (instead of being placed close to the center). Why? By the way, are there any other ways to make an image circulating other than using `UIPathBezier`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, first of all you need to override the `UIBezierPath()` constructor so you can give parameters as `originX` and `originY`, also you must use `var` instead of `let` because `var` is a simple variable and let is a `constant` and it cannot be modified in Swift.

I dont have Xcode with me but the code should look like this:

```
override func UIBezierPath(#x:CGFloat, andOriginX:CGFloat) {
}

let path = UIBezierPath(x, y)
    path.moveToPoint(CGPoint(x: x+50, y: y)) // and so one...
    path.addCurveToPoint(CGPoint(x: originX-20, y: originY),
    controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: originX+20, y: originY),
    controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: originX-10, y: originY))

    let anim = CAKeyframeAnimation(keyPath: "position")

    // set the animations path to our bezier curve
    anim.path = path.CGPath

    anim.repeatCount = Float.infinity
    anim.duration = 5.0
    image.layer.addAnimation(anim, forKey: "animate position along path")
)
```

Comment: Thank you for answering! So should `originX` and `originY` be variables? Also Xcode suggests to delete `override `.

Comment: if you should modify them later it must be `var`.

Comment: But `originX` and `originY` are the original values of the `x` and `y` coordinates of the image so they will never change. Are you sure this code works: `func UIBezierPath(#x:CGFloat, andOriginX:CGFloat)`? Thanks